# B2B Commerce Visual Force Page Not Visible To Guest (Anonymous) Users

Tags: visualforce, community, guest-user, b2b-commerce, b2b

I have a salesforce (Visualforce) B2B Store that is being built out.
I have some custom visual force pages (subscriber pages as B2B commerce calls it) that have been created.

I can access these fine when logged into the storefront.

However, when accessing as a guest (anon) site visitors (not logged into the storefront) the custom visualforce page is not visible.

Steps I have taken:
-Gone into Setup -> All Communities -> Administration -> Pages -> Enable Public Settings -> Add page to VF Page List

-Updated Guest Profile VF Page Access

-Updated Permission Set (for Guest) to have access to VF Page.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a subscriber page? If so have you added sharing rules to share the CC Subscriber Page records to the guest user? Additionally have you gone through the complete setup guide for Guest users: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.b2b_commerce_guest.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks! Yes that is what ended up working.  I should have updated this post.  Appreciate you reaching out.